# how can I increase countmouseclick +=1 to countmouseclick += 2 after selecting the hand upgrade

Tags: python

This is the basis of the code where I need help,
I want countmouseclick to = +2 but whenever I try I cant get it right. how would I go about this. hand_rect is the upgrade button and whenever I click it it multiplies the cost and works like it should it just wont at to the clicks.

```
while True:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                exit()
            if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONUP:
                if llama_rect.collidepoint(event.pos):
                   countmouseclick += 1
            if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                if countmouseclick >= upgrade_cost:
                   if hand_rect.collidepoint(event.pos):
                       countmouseclick -= upgrade_cost
                       upgrade_cost = round(upgrade_cost*2.5)
                       if llama_rect.collidepoint(event.pos):
                           countmouseclick = countmouseclick*2
```

Answer (score 1):

This should be solved reasonably easily by factoring out the amount of increase to a variable (e.g.: `llama_rect_value`).

Start the variable at `1`, but then once the "upgrade" is used, change this to `2` or whatever.

```
llama_rect_value = 1      # set the initial value of a click

while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            exit()

        elif event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONUP:
            if llama_rect.collidepoint(event.pos):
               countmouseclick += llama_rect_value          # <<-- HERE

        elif event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            if countmouseclick >= upgrade_cost:
               if hand_rect.collidepoint(event.pos):
                   countmouseclick -= upgrade_cost
                   upgrade_cost = round(upgrade_cost*2.5)
                   if llama_rect.collidepoint(event.pos):
                       countmouseclick = countmouseclick*2
                   llama_rect_value = 2                     # <<-- HERE
```

PS> Don't forget to use `if`/`else`/`elif` rather than lists of `if`, `if`, `if`.  When `event.type` is already matched, there's no point checking if it's something else.  If/else/elif handles this automatically.